# How to combine several type constraints?

Tags: haskell

Using `lenses` automatic lens generation methods I ended up with several type classes of the `HasX` type:

```
class HasPositionX s a | s -> a where
  positionX :: Lens' s a

class HasPositionY s a | s -> a where
  positionY :: Lens' s a
```

Which of course is part of a 2d vector type. Now I am looking for a way to combine those constraints into one that basically says `IsVector s a` usable like this:

```
showVec :: (Num a, IsVector v a) => v -> String
showVec a = show (view positionX a) ++ "," ++ show (view positionY a)
```

Comment: `type IsVector v a = (HasPosX v a, HasPosY v a)`

Comment: That, using the `ConstraintKinds` extension?

Comment: @user2407038 You could turn that into an answer.

Comment: He could do that ... I would accept it ... it works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You do this by defining a new record that contains only coordinates:

```
data Position = Position {
  _positionX :: Int
  _positionY :: Int
}
```

And then replace pairs of coordinate fields by a position field each. Then `IsVector` is `HasPosition` and the lenses look like `position . x` instead of `positionX`.

Comment: Sorry ... not what I am looking for. But I can see that I formulated my question quite general.